# Encoding used for JSESSIONID?

Tags: java, servlets, encoding, jsessionid

I am curious to know which encoding is used for jsessionid.

The jsessionid value always contains only alphanumeric characters but nothing else, which makes that kind of encoding safer to user in URLs.

Comment: In the future, please be clear in the question from the beginning on. You keep changing the concrete subject. This one is in fact candidate for 3 separate questions. See also http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: If your cookies are turned off and you want to sent the jsession as part of URL then it will be encoded in base 64...just an fyi as your question is not very clear

Comment: Sorry BalusC, I thought of continuing with the topic since you know the context. So, please any solution for this? proper-encoding? or shall I post as a new question? (which may require the whole explanation again)

Comment: Be to-the-point about the concrete problem in the question. As turned out in comments on my deleted answer, JSESSIONID has nothing to do with your concrete problem. Tell about the functional requirement. Show the minimum code you have as far which reproduces exactly your problem and elaborate the unexpected and expected results in detail.

Comment: I was thinking of alphanumeric encoding, so I mentioned jsessionid. Anyhow, you mentioned that unproper url encoding may cause problems. May I know, what could be the proper encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no standard for the format of the session ID.

But if you ever want to encode something to just alphanumeric, specifically a number, you can simply convert it to BASE 36, it's like hexadecimal but where hex stops at F, BASE 36 goes all the way up to Z. Straight forward.

Comment: Thanks Will. Can you please tell me how could we encode a string into alphanumeric content? I have been trying to find.

Comment: Why would you want to 'encode a string to alphanumeric content'? You might want to encode a +number+ that way.

Comment: I am not actually encoding a number, instead an encrypted value to an alphanumeric format so that it can be passed as a request parameter.

Comment: @Firefox If you want to encode a request parameter value, use URL encoding.  In Java: `URLEncoder.encode(requestParameterValue, "UTF-8")`

Answer (score 0):

The encoding for JSESSIONID is of no conceivable interest since there is no specification for what the *contents* are, other than that they are unique among currently valid sessions.

The proper encoding *for URLs* is provided by the URI class. For example a filename can be encoded thus:

```
String encodedPath = new URI(null, filename, null).toASCIIString();
```

The proper encoding for parameters within URLs, or within POST data, is provided by URLEncoder (which is misnamed).